# LINUX- What is wrong with my code in sed?

Tags: sed

I want to replace

```
ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l <USER> -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i"
PIDFile=/home/<USER>/.vnc/%H %i.pid
```

with

```
ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l root -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i"    
PIDFile=/root/.vnc/%H %i.pid
```

I have tried:

```
sed -i 's$ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l <USER> -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i" \n PIDFile=/home/<USER>/.vnc/%H %i.pid$ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l root -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i" \n PIDFile=/root/.vnc/%H %i.pid$g' file
```

I used $ instead of / for special characters. But that doesn't work, nothing is getting edited.

Please tell me what I am missing. Thx.

Got the Soution.Thx to the answerer :) :

```
sed -i 's$ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l <USER> -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i"$ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l root -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i"$g' uu && sed -i 's$PIDFile=/home/<USER>/.vnc/%H %i.pid$PIDFile=/root/.vnc/%H %i.pid$g' uu
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` primarily works on one line at a time, so you'll need to define two separate substitute operations, one for each line:

```
sed -e 's/-l <USER> -c/-l root -c/' \
    -e 's%home/<USER>%root%' \
    file
```

Note that the character after `s` is the delimiter for the regular expression. Rather than messing with backslashes, I changed to `%` in the second to avoid the collision with slashes.

If you're really worried, you can make your matches match more, but what I showed is unlikely to fail you.  It is odd that you want `/root` to replace `/home/<USER>`.  You might do better with a marker like `<HOME>` which can be set correctly.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Used:

 `sed -i 's$ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l <USER> -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i"$ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l root -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i"$g' uu && sed -i 's$PIDFile=/home/<USER>/.vnc/%H %i.pid$PIDFile=/root/.vnc/%H %i.pid$g' uu `

Comment: OK — that works too, but you can do it all with a single `sed` command, as shown.  You are allowed to use more than one line for a command, especially in a shell script.